# Garbage collection on removal of root

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a binary tree implemented in c# with a method **clear()** which **makes the root null**, thus removing the reference to the root node in the heap. This makes the root node in the heap eligible for garbage collection.

But **during a garbage collection cycle** will **only the root node be collected** and then its two children will become eligible for garbage collection in the next cycle and taking as many cycles to remove the tree as the depth of the tree **or will the whole tree in the heap be collected** in one cycle?

Answer (score 3):

The whole tree will be collected because the GC finds in one cycle ALL objects which cannot be reached. Because none of the nodes in your tree are reachable (from some live root), the entire set of nodes should be GCed.

This is an efficient way for the GC to work - but it's also a good way for it to deal with self-referential data structures such as a doubly-linked list (which would cause problems for any algorithm which didn't take "reachability from some reachable root" into account).

Answer (score 2):

Actually that depends on how long your objects have been alive.

.NET uses an algorithm named 'mark & sweep', which is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). The algorithm basically marks everything for removal, except the things that can be reached. Your objects will be removed in one iteration here.

However, naive mark & sweep will take a lot of time, since most "long-lived" objects will survive the GC. The more long-lived objects you have, the more time the GC will require to mark all objects. This is why .NET keeps track of how many GC cycles an object has survived. If it survives a couple of times, the next GC will skip the object. These are called 'generations' and are described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#generations). Simply put, more times an object has survived a GC cycle, the less frequent it will be visited by the garbage collector for removal.

However, once your structure is at some point marked as 'not referenced' by the GC, the complete structure will be removed in one single pass.